# Quickest way to edit a list in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, inlineeditsupport, ipad

I have iPad users who need to access a specific list of records for editing.  Each record just needs a single field updated, but it is a different field depending on record types.  I tried inline edit on a Visualforce page, but that did not work for editing on the iPad.

I am now using Salesforce1 and a Flexipage to deliver the list of records to update, but it still takes about half a half dozen 'clicks' per record to update data and Flexipage.  That seems like way too many.

Does anyone have suggestions for a quicker way to access a list of records with Salesforce and an iPad?

Comment: Fields on the record detail page can be edited by desktop users, seems like mobile users should have a similar option.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things about Salesforce1 is that you can ship your users off to a mobile interface that is the responsibility of Salesforce and the admin to maintain.

I would just send them to the standard record ui on a tap from the list/flexipage, unless it was truly a very small update. In that case I would probably show a + or something which expands an edit interface where they can update the field pertaining to the record type, this probably wouldn't be possible in a flexipage list, might have to roll a VF list.

Are the fields all the same type? I have done these quick updates on Boolean fields with a simple checkbox that is always exposed. Not sure how it would work with other field types.

Inline editing on the ipad is a hack and probably not the best idea. I was able to get it working by redefining some proprietary Salesforce javascript to:

```
function getEventTarget(a) {return window.event&&a.srcElement?a.srcElement:a.target;}
```

I don't recommend doing this. Inline editing is a little funky on touch devices imo anyways.

Comment: From the Flexipage, a tap leads to the record detail and another tap leads to edit.  For updating a multi select picklist, there are about 8 taps per record.  I could cut that by going straight from Flexipage to edit if that were possible.

For the checkbox you described, how did you manage to make it always exposed for SF1 users?

Comment: I rolled my own flexipage / list view with visualforce :(

Comment: Do you mean that you added an Action to your Flexipage that called a Visualforce page with a list view? Or did you somehow create a Flexipage that uses something other than basic Salesforce list views? Why not just a VF tab?

Comment: I replaced the flexipage with a VF page/tab. Flexipages did not offer what I wanted

Comment: Okay, but didn't you say you don't recommend doing that because the inline editing is funky on touch devices?

Comment: I did not use Visualforce inline editing for the checkbox. I rolled my own checkbox component using Glyphicons, AngularJS, and Ionic. https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub is a good starting point for an example usage of ionic in sf1.

Comment: I don't think that will solve my problem since you described it as funky.

Comment: You can make it not funky if you keep ux in mind and roll your own editing controls. Use a checkbox or similar toggle to show a div with the field you need to update, then use standard html controls to do the update. Most devices work fairly well with that. The downside is you have to build ui-helpers such as calendars, etc. It really depends on what fields you need to edit and what you want the project to wind up looking like. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm looking into jTable as a solution after Summer '14 thanks to this helpful blog post: http://t.co/CS22rxDPOX